# How to mock promise with data from JSON fixture

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm testing my Angular controller using mock data pulled in from a JSON file. The problem I'm running into is that my controller expects a promise, whereas my mock data is simply a JSON object.

Relevant controller code:

```
var vm = this;
var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;

playersService.getInfo({
  playerId: playerId
}).$promise.then(function(info) {
  vm.info = info;
});
```

Relevant test code:

```
$httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/test/fixtures';

$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/players/5/info').respond(
  getJSONFixture('info.json')
);
```

I'm trying to work out how to setup my test to work with the controller's promise structure.

Comment: Setup a plunkr. I think you're mistaken as to why it's not working. Why would your mock data be any different from the non-mock data? Both should return an object. A promise is set by the controller, not by the request response. But hypothetically, you can turn static data into a promise using `$q.when(yourDataStringOrObject);`. However, I don't think that's why it's failing for you.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I forgot to add `$httpBackend.flush()` before my tests.